# Short comic series with body hopping character

Tags: story-identification, comics

I am looking for a short comic series which involved one (or two) characters who can body hop around. I think I remember the two main characters being a a boy and a girl.

And there was a scene where they stood in front of a painting of their soon-to-be host, then got sucked (or in someway) into some tunnel.
After that they possessed their host, and every host body they possessed would vomit. I remembered one of the host was a bus driver.

I think the comic was not published by DC or Marvel. I forgot why they could possess people or what mystery they were trying to solve, but I remembered at the beginning of the comic they (or just the boy) were just having fun possessing those people.